# Qt QTimer is it safe to stop it this way?

Tags: c++, qt, timer

Is it safe to stop Qt's timer in it's "timeout" signal/slot function?
Can't seem to find any information in Qt documentation about the [QTimer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtimer.html#active-prop).

I have created a timer that is periodically sending a "keep alive" messages to the server.
I want this timer to be stopped if there is some kind of error while sending my message.

```
private:
   QTimer* mpKeepAliveTimer;
```

Timer is initialized like this:

```
mpKeepAliveTimer = new QTimer(/* this */);

QObject::connect(mpKeepAliveTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(OnKeepAlive()));

mpKeepAliveTimer->start(KEEP_ALIVE_PERIOD);
```

Stopped like this:

```
if (mpKeepAliveTimer != NULL) // <-- Edited
{
    if (mpKeepAliveTimer->isActive() == true)
        mpKeepAliveTimer->stop();

    delete mpKeepAliveTimer;
    mpKeepAliveTimer = NULL;
}
```

Timeout function looks like this:

```
void Classname::OnKeepAlive()
{
   if (isErrorFound == true)
      mpKeepAliveTimer->stop();   // <---- IS THIS SAFE?
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: That third code block could use refining. There's no need to stop the timer before it is destroyed. The entire block can be reduced to `delete mpKeepAliveTimer; mpKeepAliveTimer = NULL;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as you are not explicitly using Queued Connections, this is safe.
This is because the `emit timeout()` function will not return until all the slots it's connected to were processed.

If you were however using Queued Connections, it could in theory happen that there are still unprocessed timeout events in the Event Queue, so to make it hyper-safe you could use the following:

```
void Classname::OnKeepAlive()
{
    if (!mpKeepAliveTimer || !mpKeepAliveTimer->isActive()) return;

    if (isErrorFound)
    {
        mpKeepAliveTimer->stop();
    }
}
```

Note that the condition in your stop function should be `!= NULL` instead of `== NULL`. You can also write that function as follows, however:

```
if (mpKeepAliveTimer)
{
    delete mpKeepAliveTimer;
    mpKeepAliveTimer = NULL;
}
```

As already suggested in the comments, QTimer will stop itself in its destructor.

Comment: Uff.. thanks for noticing the "== NULL" thing! (I've edited this in my post) 
I've modified my timer's stopping procedure as suggested by Slavik81
(I was not sure if by destroying my timer object it's destructor would  safely stop the timeout procedures...)
Thanks Tim, thanks Slavik81